# how to convert first value as the key of array name php

Tags: php, arrays, key

how to convert first value as the key of array and php. Hi I am working on some array operations. following below is the array i have:

```
$data= array
(
    array('city', 'california','big city'),
    array('address', 'this is','address', 'zzz'),
    array('something', 'item 3','details 3'),
);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => city
            [1] => california
            [2] => big city
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => address
            [1] => this is
            [2] => address
            [3] => zzz
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => something
            [1] => item 3
            [2] => details 3
        )
        ..........
)
```

i am expecting for this result:

```
Array
(
    [city] => Array
        (
            [0] => city
            [1] => california
            [2] => big city
        )
    [address] => Array
        (
            [0] => address
            [1] => this is
            [2] => address
            [3] => zzz
    [something] => Array
        (
            [0] => something
            [1] => item 3
            [2] => details 3
        )
        ..............
)
```

above mentioned is the result .I have already tried with array function array_keys and array_values but it won't working. giv me a helping hand

Comment: can we see how you're building the array to begin with?

Comment: How did you generate this array?

Comment: $ddd = array
(
    array('city', 'california','big city'),
array('address', 'this is','address', 'zzz'),
array('something', 'item 3','details 3'),
    
);

Comment: wait .. you're manually creating the array? Why don't you just do `'city' => array('other', 'values')`?

Comment: if received array is like this, how can we change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `forEach`

```
 $data= array
(
    array('city', 'california','big city'),
    array('address', 'this is','address', 'zzz'),
    array('something', 'item 3','details 3'),
);
 $res=[];
foreach($data as $val){
    $res[$val[0]] = $val;
}
print_r($res);
```

Comment: although correct, the code at the top is all manual.. I'd prefer suggesting correct array creation to begin .. (but I may be being pedantic)

Comment: can we do this without loop.

Comment: @user11246426 loop is simple and efficient.Now we can do with `Array#reduce`  achieve the same result.But its not  necessary for this case